# Saving file shows Permission Denied though permission granted

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm saving image from glide to device. I'm asking for permission in first App run cause that's what my app do.

```
 final File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DesiJewellery/");
public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, String img_title) {

    fname = img_title;
    myDir.mkdirs();
    File image = new File(myDir, fname);


    FileOutputStream outStream;
    if (image.exists()) {
        image.delete();
    }
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Design saved - " + img_title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
       // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // this one to show in gallery:

}
```

It's working fine in emulator, but in real device it shows

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DesiJewellery/m_aad14.jpg (Permission denied)

Permission Check. I run it on MainActivity.

```
public void isStoragePermissionGranted() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

**P.S.- I have 2 Real devices. It's working in Mashmallow and Nougat Emulator but Problem is in Only Oreo.**

Comment: There's nowhere in code snippet, the code responsible for permission check. Please add all the relevant code. Without it, we can only guess what's wrong here.

Comment: Could you please explain what permissions, you have acquired?

Comment: @AnuChaudhary read & write .

Comment: @Jay edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to save image file in android oreo update. How to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47787577/608639) (per comment below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
AsyncTask fileTask = new AsyncTask() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyApplication");
if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            }
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String name = " "+n+".jpg";
File pictureFile = new File(directory, name);
pictureFile.createNewFile();
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
   finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
   out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
 }
};
fileTask.execute();
```

Refer this for [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446742/java-io-filenotfoundexception-permission-denied-only-in-oreo)

Comment: Don't just copy paste from anywhere. First, understand the question, and  then post the answer.

Comment: I have checked your question and then found it suitable. So posted to you.

Comment: Have you tried above already?

Comment: if you have chekced, then you must know that my code is updated version of your code.

Comment: I can't see async task there. Have you used it with async?

Comment: I don't have to use async. and fyi, Saving Code is absolutely fine. Problem is with runtime permission.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that thing. You might be having directory created in storage also. But No image is saved there, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182065/discussion-between-anu-chaudhary-and-mukeshsoni).

Comment: thanks for help but i got the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787577/unable-to-save-image-file-in-android-oreo-update-how-to-do-it

Answer (score 1):

You should add **WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION** in Android Mainifest like below :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
tools:node="replace"/>
```